# Is there a term to describe female names derived from a male name?

Tags: gender, names

As an example there is the name Alexandra, a female name derived from the Greek male name Alexandros.

Is there a term used to describe this process? As there are terms to describe to process of obtaining a part of a name from a name of a male ancestor (patronymics).

Comment: No, there is no special term for such personal names. Nor is there a term for family names that vary by gender, like _Ivanovich_ and _Ivanovna_.